# access a server through url in browser

Tags: ftp, network-protocols

I have set up a ssh server on my desktop through Cygwin. I can access this remotely through putty. However, should I be able to type `ftp://ip address/ code here` into a browser and be able to access it. I cant do this at moment so have I configured it wrong.

Never done this before.

Comment: You must have used SSH tunnels right.. ?

Comment: What does you think that being able to log into a server via SSH also allows you to log into it via FTP?

Answer (score 0):

To access via ftp protocol like you mention you will need to enable ftpd on your server. SSH access is different to FTP and won't just "work"

Edit:

More info here [Cygwin Manaual](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188155/Installing-an-SSH-SFTP-Server-on-Windows)